# Livescript. require! and execute

Tags: livescript

How do I do something that transpiles into this:

```
var foo = require('foo')()
```

Doing that doesn't work:

```
require! { 
  \foo !
}
```

of course I can run it right after the `require!`, but I was hoping for a shorter form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with `require!`, I would just use the original `require`

`foo = require('foo')!`

Answer (score 1):

incase you are going to be import a few packages
you can also do:

```
require! {
  bar
  foo
  'some-thing'
}
someThing = someThing!
foo = foo!
```